# Display an image in a non-copyable format on Web

Tags: javascript, html, image

So what I am aiming to achieve is to have a small icon on a page which cannot be copied (at least not without doing a screenshot).

I realise that an advanced user will always be able to seize the image, but I am looking to deter this if possible. Using JS is an option, but server side languages are not.

My current possible thoughts include:

- Using a background image (Can't highlight and copy)
- Using HTML5 Canvas (New browsers only though)

My question is, what is the best way I can achieve this? How can I make an image hardest to copy using only HTML/HTML5/JS, with no server side languages?

Comment: I think both of your thoughts are fine. Do you have an actual question?

Comment: You could position an equally sized transparent image on top of the image, so the user will get the transparent image if they try and copy. And now I feel dirty.

Comment: Flickr use a div with a transparent png background over the actual image so the right click "sees" the div and not the image.

Comment: I think these days, users are either clever enough to get the image by others means, or are too stupid to even know how to right-click, there is no in between. I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: What Matt Cain suggested is what Flickr does (or used to do at least, haven't tried in a while). In Chrome though I would always just right-click, "Inspect element" and press delete in order to get at the image if that's enough deterrent.

Answer (score 3):

All of the suggestions in the comments are fine and do what you want.

Since none of them will actually do anything but hide the image from the casual user who right clicks only, I would recommend you use whatever takes the least amount of time to implement.

I feel like I have typed to much, and I have stopped caring about this question.  Why do people do this?  We have laws to protect intellectual property, and that's what you have to rely on.  Once you show the image on the web, anyone can steal it, if there is someone who wants the image, they will already know how to look in their cache, or view script, or save page as download, or...

If you show it on a public page, there is no way to prevent it from being copied.

Comment: I realise that there's no way to prevent it from being copied.. hence "hardest to copy". Thanks for the help though. Basic prevention is all I am trying to do here, just wondered if there was a way of doing it I didn't know about. Thanks!